# Can not use startsWith Discord.js question

Tags: discord, discord.js

this is my role command.
I'm trying to use `startsWith` to give roles: if the arg's first letters are the same as the role, it should be assigned to the user.

```
exports.run = async function (msg,args) {
  if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
  const member = msg.mentions.members.first();
  const name = msg.mentions.users.size ? args.replace(/ +/, ' ').split(' ')[1] : args;
  const role = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(name.toLowerCase()));
  if (name && !role.size) return msg.channel.send("Role Not found");
  if (name && role.size > 1) return msg.channel.send("There is similar roles , Please supply more letters");
  await member.addRole(role);
  msg.channel.send(`**Role \`${role}\`  Given to **${member} Succesflly`);
};
```

I updated the current code but still can not give roles depending or first letters on args !

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `name`, the roles from `msg.guild.roles` and the value of `role`? What do those values show, what does your code currently do and what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Using the function version of `.find()` was a good idea, but your mistake is in the way you use [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith): it's not a property, it's a method.

```js
const role = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(args.split(/ +/g).slice(1).join(' ').toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: `TypeError: args.split(...).slice(...).join(...).toLowerCase(...).first is not a function` it's not working @federico

Comment: I updated the code using cleaner way but still not working any ideas ??

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer, there should've been no `first` (btw that was from your original code)