# Having issue using startsWith discord.js question

Tags: discord.js

this is my role command.
I'm trying to use `startsWith` to give roles: if the arg's first letters are the same as the role, it should be assigned to the user.

```
exports.run = async function (msg,args) {
  if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;
  const member = msg.mentions.members.first();
  const name = msg.mentions.users.size ? args.replace(/ +/, ' ').split(' ')[1] : args;
  const role = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(name.toLowerCase()));
  if (name && !role.size) return msg.channel.send("Role Not found");
  if (name && role.size > 1) return msg.channel.send("There is similar roles , Please supply more letters");
  await member.addRole(role);
  msg.channel.send(`**Role \`${role}\`  Given to **${member} Succesflly`);
};
```

Trying to use : $role @member ad 
`ad` is first letter for `admin` role as an example .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not use startsWith Discord.js question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579465/can-not-use-startswith-discord-js-question)

Answer (score 0):

`args` usually is an array.

Try `args[1]` instead of `args`. For educational purposes, you could also try `console.log(args);`.